# Volley JsonObjectRequest POST Request

Tags: android, android-volley

Peeps, I have some problem in understanding the working of volley library, so answer with proper material which can guide me to unobserved aspects of volley is what I am looking forward to.

1. How does my POST parameters are bind in network request. When I send params after overriding getParams() and by sending jsonObject directly in network request I don't receive any response but some server errors.
2. Since I am testing my backend on Postman, what postman actually does(my Observation) is it bind the params in url itself. When I copy paste the url in my android code it responds positively.

So, should I code to append my params to url or there's another way round?
I have alredy tried making changes to getHeaders() but it doesn't respond too!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a JsonObjectRequest with a jsonObject containing all your params.

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("token", "8327483274823");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(params);

JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL,jsonObject ,
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
       try {
           //Do stuff here
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
   @Override
   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       //Handle Errors here
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried this too! It doesn't work out and I get a server error :BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://XXXXXXXXXX:8080/g/v1/login/

Comment: It means u have misspelled your url. Check the url again. Are you using localhost?

Comment: I am accepting calls at port 8080 . I knowingly made that change. I had other services running on default port.